# Getting unload to work with a button cross-browser's

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window.onunload

I am wondering if I can have the unload method in Javascript do a `button.click;` or a `document.getElementById('target').click();`

The reason for this is I want to clear the information in the browser but I can't seem to get the unload method to work right. But I don't even know if the unload method is capable of doing a `button.click` or a `document.getElementById('target').click();` Is there like a list of things this method can or cannot do? here is the code I am trying to get working.

```
  window.onunload=leave;

     function leave() {
//alert("Leaving");
    document.getElementById('kioskform:broswerCloseSubmit').click();
   
}
```

The alert seems to be showing in everything ("IE, FireFox,Safari") but in Chrome ('don't know why) but i can't seem to get the clear options i am using to work with the unload method. Not to mention I am wondering if there is a good way to detect which browser the individual is using to load in different parts of the unload script any idea's or suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just call the code that the button click would call in your `unload` handler? Also, you should consider using a standard method of event registration: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: What the button is calling is a a4j:jsFunction I don't know if i can just copy that over there and you think it will work that way?

Comment: Nope wasn't able to completely work. I rewrote the document part of script to get it to work for IE but only seems to work for IE. is there something off with the unload method? I uploaded an updated version of the code.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry, I have no idea how to properly deal with the obtrusive way JSF does things.

Comment: its okay i probably should of mentions its a jsf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use [`jQuery`](http://www.jquery.com)  , you could use the [`DirtyForm`](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/dirtyform)  plugin. This would accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: How would this work could you explain I can add jQuery to it if need be but what is Dirtyform?

Comment: Dirty form essentially monitors your form fields for changes, and triggers the onunload message if there are any changes to your data. This may not apply to you, but you can at least look at the source to find out how they do it!

Comment: Okay is there a way i can do this for cross broswer? like run a specific code for IE only , for Firefox , Chrome and Safari? also how would I use it for the onUnload methods?